# Problems with mouseover and mouseout events in a continuous jQuery content slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jquery-animate, setinterval

I have tried to built a continuous content slider in jQuery.

If you don't hover over it, then it works fine, it slides (even though I feel like I made it happen in a wrong way).

When you hover it then it stops, but only for 2 seconds. As you'd imagine, it should stay stopped until the cursor is removed. Maybe the interval is not cleared properly?

Generally the whole thing works improperly when you starts to hover/unhover.

Here's a demo of my plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/T5Gt3/

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.productSlider = function(options) {

    var defaults = {
        speed: 2000
    };

    var config = $.extend(defaults, options);

    this.each(function() {

        var $this = $(this),
            $scrollable = $this.find('#content-product-slider-inner'),
            timeLeft;

        function animateScrollable() {
            $scrollable.animate({ left: '-120px' }, config.speed, 'linear', function() {
                $scrollable.css({ left: '0px' }).find('a:first-child').remove().appendTo($scrollable);
            });
        };

        animateScrollable();

        var timer = setInterval(animateScrollable, config.speed);

        $scrollable.mouseover(function() {

            $scrollable.stop();
            clearInterval(timer);

        });

        $scrollable.mouseout(function() {

            animateScrollable();
            var timer = setInterval(animateScrollable, config.speed);

        });

    });

    return this;

};
})(jQuery);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".event_list_inner_wrapper").live({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).find('.front_side').fadeOut(600).hide();
        $(this).find('.back_side').fadeIn(600).show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).find('.back_side').fadeOut(600).hide();
        $(this).find('.front_side').fadeIn(600).show();
    }






});
```

That's code I used for a project that was similar to your description. Basically, bind the mice events, and do your thing.

Comment: live() is deprecated in the latest version of jQuery, so I tried the equivalent on() function. Unfortunately it doesn't change anything.